# Value of v-bind is not changing when data changes. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I have a function changeActive which changes the value of active boolean. But even though the value of active changes (i checked using console.log) the new value is not passed in the v-bind:'active' to the child component.

```
<template>
<div style="width:300px; margin: auto;">
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[0]'
      :active='active'
      style="margin: auto;"
      />
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[1]'
      style="float: right;"
      />
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[2]'
      />
      <RatingLabel 
      :rating='rating[3]'
      style="margin: auto;"
      />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import RatingLabel from '../atomic/RatingLabel'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
      components: {
            RatingLabel,
      },

      data() {
            return {
                  active: false,
            }
      },

      methods: {
            changeActive() {
                  setTimeout(function(){ 
                        this.active = !this.active;
                        console.log(this.active)
                   }, 3000);
            }
      },

      mounted() {
            this.changeActive()
      },

      computed: mapState(['rating'])
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is undefined in the callback function, you must assign it to a global variable `vm` before calling `setTimeout` and then use it inside the callback :

```
    changeActive() {
                 let vm=this;
                  setTimeout(function(){ 
                        vm.active = !vm.active;
                        console.log(vm.active)
                   }, 3000);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

`function(){}` -> `() => {}`, Because you can access `this`

```js
           changeActive() {
                  setTimeout(() => { 
                        this.active = !this.active;
                        console.log(this.active)
                   }, 3000);
```